# Swift, can't create a dictionary to hold key values?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a dictionary to hold these values but I get the following error

```
import Security
var keychainQuery: Dictionary =

            [
                kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecAttrService: service,
                kSecAttrAccount: userAccount,
                dataFromString: kSecValueData
            ]

Cannot convert the expression's type 'Dictionary' to type '@lvalue Unmanaged<AnyObject>!'
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases with Swift, I've found it much less painful to declare the types of the dictionary. In your case:

```
var keychainQuery: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
    ...
]
```

Should work.

Comment: It doesn't work since keys like kSecClass are of type Unmanaged<AnyObject>. Even if you pass that as the Dictionaries type, it will fail since AnyObject and Unmanaged<AnyObject> aren't hashable - they don't conform to the Hashable protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know for now, building a Keychain query with a Swift Dictionary is **not possible**.
Keys like *kSecClass* are of a non-hashable type and so can't be put in a Dictionary (that strictly needs items that share the same protocol btw.).

One of the ways I have seen to circumvent this problem is to use an NSDictionary and pass keys and values as Arrays. This code only seems to work in *Xcode 6 Beta 1*.

```
var query = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, service, account, secret], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecValueData])
```

Another approach can be seen [on this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629075/1665702).
Based on that approach you would **convert** all the key and value constants to Strings using the **`\()`** syntax.
The query would then look like this:

```
var query = ["\(kSecClass)": "\(kSecClassGenericPassword)", "\(kSecAttrService)": service, "\(kSecAttrAccount)": account, "\(kSecValueData)": secretData]
```

I tested this solution and got an error saying that I'm trying to add already existing keys. So this doesn't seem to work either.