# How to store a user's data to the device?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a sign in view. I have two `UITextField`'s which are for the user's email and password. When user clicks the 'Sign In' button, these two parameters are sent to my API and check to see if the user exists. If this user exists, my API gets the user's email, name, status and token, and return the JSON result to me. The token had expire date. Hence, I need to store the token and email in the device so the user doesn't have to repeatedly sign in.

I am newbie.So,any code help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

I have imported LockSmith.swift and LockSmithRequest.swift into my project.And I had also added KeyChainService.swift same as matt blog to project.But I am occurring these problem and my xcode is 6.2.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app)

Comment: I dont know about Objective C.If u dont mind,can u please share in Swit.And I am newbie,too.Thank You

Comment: `Keychain` is better option over `NSUserDefaults`. [Keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324285/adding-items-to-and-querying-the-ios-keychain-with-swift). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keychains](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) should be used to store users' emails and passwords. Here are some posts that talk about doing this in Swift:

- [Adding Items to and Querying the iOS Keychain with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324285/adding-items-to-and-querying-the-ios-keychain-with-swift)
- [Adding item to keychain using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113313/adding-item-to-keychain-using-swift)
- [Example Code for Using Swift to Save and Query iOS Keychain](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/06/21/example-ios-keychain-swift-save-query/)

Comment: Can i also store the token that are back from API?

Comment: In the last link I posted the author has a `saveToken` method. I suggest you try to follow that post as closely as you can. If it doesn't work then come back and update your question.

Comment: @Suragh,I have imported LockSmith.swift and LockSmithRequest.swift into my project.And I had also added KeyChainService.swift same as matt blog to project.But I am occurring these problem and my xcode is 6.2."http://puu.sh/gGwNV/fb55409cbf.png"

Comment: At the bottom of the blog there is an update that says: "Xcode 6.1: @godzirra let me know on Twitter that doing let kSecClassValue = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() as NSString no longer works on Seed 2. Instead, you need to do let kSecClassValue = NSString(format: kSecClass). This applies to all of the arguments we provide to the keychain queries listed at the top of the snippet."

Comment: I updated your question so that your progress is more visible to other people. You can make further updates to your question yourself as you make more progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store data within your app, you can use one of the following

- **NSUserDefaults** (Suitable for basic small details)
- **CoreData** (Suitable for large amounts of dynamically changing data that needs to be queried)
- **Files** (Suitable for static content)

In your case, I would suggest using **NSUserDefaults**.

Assuming you have the information to be stored in the form of **NSDictionary**. You can follow these steps:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"token"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Later you can retrieve this key like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP wants the answer in Swift. Also, wouldn't it unsecure to save passwords like this? I think Keychain is what should be used.

Comment: Umm i dont know the Objective C Syntax...Sorry.I am newbie to Swift

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a very simple drop-in Keychain wrapper, you could take a look at this:

https://github.com/ashleymills/keychain.swift

Comment: Thanks for your effort,Ashley.I am really appreciate for your help.It really helpful to newbie in swift like me.But,I will be glad to accept it if your library support for swift 1.2.Thank You,Sir.

Comment: @Htarwara6245 The current version does support Swift 1.2

Comment: ,thank you sir.I gonna use your lib now.If any bug or issue occur,i will write it on github.